# If $\sqrt{SQ_{XX}} = 0.15 \sqrt{ SQ_{XY} }$ and $r = 0.76$, find $\beta_1$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

> If $\sqrt{SQ_{XX}} = 0.15 \sqrt{ SQ_{XY} }$ and $r = 0.76$, find $\beta_1$.

**Attempt.** I'm almost there but I need an equation relating these quantities with $\beta_1$. Squaring both sides on the first equality, we obtain $ SQ_{XX} = (15/100)^2 SQ_{XY}$, from which we obtain, after a little algebraic manipulation,

$$
\displaystyle \left( \frac{100}{15} \right)^2 = \frac{SQXY}{SQXX} = \hat{\beta}_1 = 44.44.
$$

We're given that $r = 0.76$.

Since $\hat \beta_1 >0$, we have $r = \sqrt{R^2} = 0.76$, so $r^2 = R^2 = 0.76^2 = 0.5776$. Now notice that

$$
R^2 = \frac{SQReg}{SQT} = \frac{ \sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y}_i)^2  }{ \sum(Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 } = 0.5776.
$$

There are also other ways to express the quotioent above. We have

$$ 
SQReg = \hat \beta_1 \left[ \sum X^2_i - \frac{(\sum X_i)^2}{n}  \right] = \hat\beta_1 \left[ \sum X^2_i   - n(\bar{X})^2\right]
$$

and

$$
SQT = \sum \left(Y_i - \bar{Y} \right)^2 = \sum Y_i^2 - n(\bar{Y})^2.
$$

Putting it all together

$$
\frac{SQReg}{SQT} = \hat\beta_1^2 \left[ \frac{ \sum X^2_i   - n(\bar{X})^2  }{ \sum Y_i^2 - n(\bar{Y})^2  } \right]
$$

and this is where I'm currently stuck! Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe that by "$\beta_1$" the question *must* mean either the *estimated* slope or the *estimated standard slope.*  You cannot know the true parameter $\beta_1$ no matter how many statistics you might have, unless you have a complete census of a finite population.

Comment: @whuber yes... that's what I suspected. I also noticed that this problem couldn't be solved according to the equations given in the class notes. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: What is supposed to be SQ?

Comment: @POC sim of squares